# Search through scripts of (multiple) cimplicity screens

Tags: search

We are using Cimplicity to operate some installations at our plant. The frontend consists of a lot of .cim files, which are the screens presented to the operator. These files are built with 'cimedit', which is basically a graphical click and drag program with which you can assemble the screens. Each object you drag onto the screen has the option to run a script, which brings me to my problem.

Because each screen contains a lot of small scripts and functions it is hard to keep track of what does what. For example I'm trying to figure out where a certain table from my database is being accessed or updated. Since the files all seem to be compressed (or so) I can't use a regular 'search the contents of this file' search.

Things I've tried so far are searching using windows, with the content option enabled and also tried the compression option. This had no success. It makes sense because like I said, the files seem to be compressed, so the actual script is not stored in plain text.

So, my question in short:

*How do I search all the scripts of (preferably multiple) cimplicity screens?*

Any tips on how to search compressed files are also very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon another stackoverflow post while searching for a better windows search tool and ended up finding this post: https://superuser.com/questions/26593/best-way-to-confidently-search-files-and-contents-in-windows-without-using-an

This posts recommends [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home) and it is actually possible to search through the .cim files with this tool.